# How can I display PDF on ASP.NET Core Razor page?

Tags: pdf, asp.net-core

I want to display pdf on razor page.

I just used iframe tag but it doesn't work.

```
<iframe id="iframepdf" src="files/example.pdf"></iframe>
```

Is there any other way to display it?

Comment: You should show your attempt at solving the problem. Please edit the question to include a [MCVE].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was my error before.

I just used embed tag instead of iframe.

Like this.

```
<embed src="~/contract.pdf#navpanes=0&scrollbar=0" width="100%" height="800px">
```

---

Just close Download plugin like IDM.